# separate one package.json in two package.json in electron.js and react

Tags: reactjs, npm, electron, package.json, electron-builder

I'm developing an application using Electron and React. Currently, I'm using a single package.json file, but I'm encountering issues with dependencies. Electron attempts to build dependencies that are not required, and vice versa.

Is it possible to separate the package.json into two separate files, one for Electron and one for React?

For example, react require canvas but electron-builder try to rebuild this as dependencies

Thank you.